# Node-webkit specific javascript callback/promise issues

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, node-webkit

recently ive been writing a program to modify an android device and ran across node-webkit. i have a beautiful GUI now and want to implement adbkit so that the tools will be platform independent.

i have both adbkit and bluebird modules installed to node-modules/ and as far as i can tell everything should work correctly (im very new to the idea of callbacks and promises)

The issue is that even with no device connected im getting a success return 'Done pushing...' instead of 'something went wrong'. Ive tried just testing client.listDevices and get the same issue: positive return regardless of whether device is actually connected.

If anyone has experience with node ADBKIT or JS Promises i would be very grateful for some guidance.

Here is my JS code :

```
var Promise = require('bluebird')
var adb = require('adbkit')
var client = adb.createClient()

client.listDevices()
  .then(function(devices) {
    return Promise.map(devices, function(device) {
      return client.push(device.id, 'test.txt', '/data/local/tmp/foo.txt')
        .then(function(transfer) {
          return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            transfer.on('progress', function(stats) {
              console.log('[%s] Pushed %d bytes so far',
                device.id,
                stats.bytesTransferred)
            })
            transfer.on('end', function() {
              console.log('[%s] Push complete', device.id)
              resolve()
            })
            transfer.on('error', reject)
          })
        })
    })
  })
  .then(function() {
    alert('Done pushing test.txt to all connected devices')
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    alert('Something went wrong:', err.stack)
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To trigger `catch` you need to `throw` something. So if you want to get error on no devices, you should add `if (devices.length <= 0) throw new Error('error description')`

Comment: like i said im very new to this part of javascript, but to my knowledge a throw is just a customization of an error so that without it the default is used


i.e. (from w3schools)


    try {
        adddlert("Welcome guest!");
    }
    catch(err) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = err.message;
    }

This returns adddlert is undefined

Comment: yeah, but do you have `try` in your script?

Comment: no i dont, and my lack of experience is going to show here, but ive never used callbacks (or promises as i am here) before. This code is copied line for line from an ADBKIT tutorial with only the client.push variables changed.

Im scouring the web to learn about these features, but wanted to get some sort of baseline working to build from. i wouldnt know where to  add a [try] to this script to attempt to get it to work

Comment: Just in your example lacking of devices is not an error, if you will not define this case as error, it will be never so. You don't need to add `try` will be enough just assign cases of error by just `trow` errors

Comment: okay, clearly my education doesnt match my desired result. lots more to learn
   id like to start with a way just to verify a device is connected or not.

var adb = require('adbkit');
var client = adb.createClient();
alert(client.listDevices())

in my mind this should alert any devices connected, and idk what if no device is connected, but regardless the return is always [object Promise]

and i dont understand why

https://www.npmjs.org/package/adbkit

Comment: because javascript is asynchronous and promises are just functions with callbacks, you will get data only on callback

Comment: okay, i ran this script from node with an android emulator connected and am starting to understand. i am able to successfully push a file to the /sdcard but as you said without any error if no device is connected. The question then becomes what is client.listDevices() really doing? i assumed it would check to see if the adb server lists any connected devices and return an error if that wasnt true but thats not the case. I need to set the script to return an error if no device is detected, but dont know how to determine that

Comment: It creates function that do some stuff and then call function inside `.then()` and passing resulted data to it. That is basically how promises work. So you should check data inside function followed by `listDevices()` and then throw error

Comment: okay so more like this?

`client.listDevices().then(function(){dosomething},function(){dosomethingforerror},function(){dosomethingforprogress})`

i appreciate your help. each response im getting more understanding of how this works. 
If the above is correct, what would cause an error for listDevices() if not that no device is connected?

Comment: devices are passed to your next function, so you can `.then(function(devices) { console.log(devices); ...`

Comment: no, not like that. all you have to do is add my line of code from answer to your function

Comment: AHAH! okay now im starting to get the big picture. ^that now returns [id:emulator-5554, type: offline]
(or [] with no device connected)
so what i want to do is run my other commands like push only if that check != null (or "" whichever it needs to be)

Comment: okay new frustration. in a node terminal i get this
> client.listDevices().then(function(devices) { console.log(devices)})
[object Object]
> [ { id: 'emulator-5554', type: 'offline'}]

and in my program with an if,else statement i get an alert 'no device detected' when no device is connected, but when a device IS connected i get an alert object Object instead of the actual info...

youve been extremely helpful and i really appreciate your patience with me

Comment: you should use `util.inspect` to view full info about object http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options

Comment: i just realized i dont need to display the actual info just verify that its there. thanks to your help ive come up with this

`var adb = require('adbkit');
var client = adb.createClient();
var Promise = require('bluebird');

function checkDevices(){
client.listDevices().then(function(devices){
if(devices != "") {alert('device detected')}
else {alert('no device detected')}
})
};`

Comment: also now that ive done this really roundabout thing, i realize that your actual answer accomplishes this exactly in one line. I will go with the throw you suggested instead now that i understand how it works. Thanks again for clearing that up for me!